# G29 difference between Q and D

Tags: marlin

I was wondering what the exact difference between the switches Q and D for the `G29` command is? They seem to do the same:

```
[D<bool>]   
Dry-Run mode. Just probe the grid but don’t update the bed leveling data

[Q<bool>]   
Query the current leveling state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Yes they are different, but whether `Q` is active depends on the a configuration setting, else it gets ignored and a regular `G29` will be executed.

---

### Option 'D'

With option `D` the `G29` code is being run in dry-run mode:

```
 *  D  Dry-Run mode. Just evaluate the bed Topology - Don't apply
 *     or alter the bed level data. Useful to check the topology
 *     after a first run of G29.
```

If you look into the [source code of `G29` for ABL](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/gcode/bedlevel/abl/G29.cpp) the `D` option will set the boolean `abl.dryrun`:

```
abl.dryrun = parser.boolval('D') || TERN0(PROBE_MANUALLY, no_action);
```

This boolean will cause many parts of the code to be excluded, e.g.:

```
// Unapply the offset because it is going to be immediately applied
// and cause compensation movement in Z
...
// Auto Bed Leveling is complete! Enable if possible. 
...
probe.preheat_for_probing(LEVELING_NOZZLE_TEMP, LEVELING_BED_TEMP);
...
// vector_3 planeNormal related code
...
extrapolate_unprobed_bed_level();
...
// Create the matrix but don't correct the position yet
...
// Correct the current XYZ position based on the tilted plane.
...
// Unapply the offset because it is going to be immediately applied
// and cause compensation movement in Z
...
// Auto Bed Leveling is complete! Enable if possible.
```

### Option 'Q'

Option `Q` in command `G29` code is available when manually probing is active in the [configuration.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/Configuration.h#L1067) file:

```
/**
 * The "Manual Probe" provides a means to do "Auto" Bed Leveling without a probe.
 * Use G29 repeatedly, adjusting the Z height at each point with movement commands
 * or (with LCD_BED_LEVELING) the LCD controller.
 */
//#define PROBE_MANUALLY
```

From the sources:

```
 *
 *  To do manual probing simply repeat G29 until the procedure is complete.
 *  The first G29 accepts parameters. 'G29 Q' for status, 'G29 A' to abort.
 *
 *  Q  Query leveling and G29 state
```

Using the `Q` in the command will set the boolean variable `seenQ`  which enables extra output as if in debugging mode.

```
  // G29 Q is also available if debugging
  #if ENABLED(DEBUG_LEVELING_FEATURE)
    if (seenQ || DEBUGGING(LEVELING)) log_machine_info();
    if (DISABLED(PROBE_MANUALLY) && seenQ) G29_RETURN(false);
  #endif
```

When going through the code, you stumble again on:

```
abl.dryrun = parser.boolval('D') || TERN0(PROBE_MANUALLY, no_action);
```

In the first option ('D') the first part of the statement already was `true`, so the latter part was of no interest as this statement is an `OR` statement. Now (for the 'Q' option) the latter part is of interest, the first part rendered `false`. The latter part is a [Marlin ternary macro](https://marlinfw.org/docs/development/coding_standards.html):

```
TERN0(OPTION, T)    If OPTION is enabled emit T otherwise emit 0 (false).
```

So, if `PROBE_MANUALLY` was enabled/defined in the configuration.h file, the ternary macro returns the `no_action` (a "one"/`true`, as this a boolean: `no_action = seenA || seenQ`), otherwise a "zero"/`false`. And if so, the `abl.dryrun` is `true` and all code as listed in the 'D' option will be omitted as well. But, additional exclusion apply for the `no_action`; this will cause the function to be exited early ([line 478](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/gcode/bedlevel/abl/G29.cpp#L478)):

```
if (no_action) G29_RETURN(false);
```

---

*So far a generic answer, the following is specific for the Ender 5 Plus.*

In looking into another question from you it appears that the printer used is the Ender 5 Plus. If you are using stock firmware, you can peek into the sources as they are being shared (through their [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16596EvFWv9C9ClbavmHPc4J3MJ4_N3h_)) by Creality for the Ender 5 Plus.

Digging into the sources, the firmware version is from the 1.1.x branch, they reference to 2016/2017 Marlin development. If you look into the sources, the configuration file doesn't define the needed `PROBE_MANUALLY` for the `Q` to become active in a `G29 Q` sent to the printer, in such a case the `Q` is ignored and a regular `G29` will be executed. Do note that the implementation of the `G29` code is able to handle the `Q` option, but because it is not enabled in this configuration it will not work.